# Parse data from webhooks

Tags: php

I am parsing data from webhook using this:
`$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);`
So I have array of data in json file. How can I can get all of fields be as variables in json (Like { time: 'now' } be variable $time='now';

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what's not quite right with it?  Also, whilst this is possible, it's not a great idea - dynamic variables aren't easy to debug, and the code always looks confusing

Answer (score 0):

PHP has an `extract` function that will convert array keys into variables. Whether that is a good idea is a totally different question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true)

return arrray expample array('time':'10:00');


you can get variable example

echo $data['time'];

oupt put => 10:00
```